# Efficient program to scale values in embedded context

Tags: c, math, arm, largenumber

I want to scale my input values between 0 and 32767. For context, this program is running on an ARM M0, and I would like to avoid any float operations. My input types are u32 and output types are u16. I have this so far, where I explicitly check for an overflow when doing a large multiplication. If not, I simply proceed to multiply the numbers. Is this method of checking for overflow an efficient way of achieving desired scaling?

```
uint16_t scaling(uint32_t in, uint32_t base)
{
    uint32_t new_base = INT16_MAX; // 32767

    if (in >= base) {
        return (uint16_t)new_base;
    }

    if (in != ((in * new_base) / new_base) ) {
        // overflow, increase bit width!
        uint64_t tmp = in * (uint64_t)new_base;
        tmp /= base;
        return (uint16_t)(tmp);
    }

    // simply multiply
    uint32_t tmp = (in * new_base) / base;

    if (tmp > new_base) {
        tmp = new_base; // clamp
    }

    return (uint16_t)tmp;
}
```

For example, for sample "large" input of (in=200000, base=860000) expected output is 7620 (which this program does give back)

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to take 15 upper bits.

Comment: sorry but i didn't quite understand

Comment: Ah, maybe it was me. Looks like your input range is dynamic

Comment: yes, for example in the sample test case, the input has a base of 860000, so it can go from 0 to 860000. I would like to scale it down between 0 and 32767.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following variation on OP's code precalculates the threshold where `in * new_base` overflows into 64-bit, and saves the final check `if (tmp > new_base)` which is redundant once `in < base`.

```
uint16_t scaling(uint32_t in, uint32_t base)
{
    static const uint32_t new_base = INT16_MAX; // 2^15 - 1 = 32767
    static const uint32_t in32 = (uint32_t)(((uint64_t)UINT32_MAX + 1) / INT16_MAX); // 2^32 / (2^15 - 1) = 131076

    if (in >= base) {
        return (uint16_t)new_base;
    }

    if(in < in32) {
        return (uint16_t)((in * new_base) / base);
    }

    return (uint16_t)(((uint64_t)in * new_base) / base);
}
```

As a side comment, at least [one compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/3MPaMf) (running with the default optimizations) will replace the multiplication `in * new_base` with the cheaper `(in << 15) - in` when `new_base = INT16_MAX` is declared `const uint32_t` but not when declared as just `uint32_t`.